# The "Add delimited text layer" button does not show (QGIS 1.8.0)

Tags: qgis

I want to create a point map layer on the basis of an CSV file with XY data, with the "Add Delimited Text Layer" button. However, this button does not show. Also, it is not possible to add an Excel (.xls) file via "Add vector layer".

I'm working in a secondary education school. The computer expert of our school has installed QGIS 1.8.0. On my own PC and laptop (same version of QGIS: 1.8.0), the tool does show and works fine. But on the computers at my school, the tool is simply not available. Why is that? Is it caused by the security settings our our school network system? Can it be that the "Add Delimited Text Layer" tool automatically creates a temporary map layer, which is stored somewhere, and that the security settings of our school network does not allow this?

Answer (score 5):

The Add Delimited Text Layer is a plugin that has to be enabled.  You can enable using `Plugins->Manage Plugins` search for "Delimited", and tick the checkbox.